# How to add images in a objectlistview

Tags: c#, listview, imagelist, objectlistview

I am extremely confused on how to use this control properly, what my attempts are is to create a media library and to show cover art of movies in a detailed view but I am not understanding how to associate a particular column with a particular image. Any advice/tips?

I have a model object that I am using which contains movie details

```
public class MovieDetails
    {
        public string MovieName { get; set; }
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string CoverArtUri { get; set; }
        public string MovieUri { get; set; }
        public string DownloadUri { get; set; }
        public int ItemCount { get; set; }
    }

//setup columns
        Generator.GenerateColumns(objectListView2, typeof(MovieDetails), true);

//show all movies from a-z
            DisplayAllMovies();

public void DisplayAllMovies()
        {
            try
            {
                objectListView2.UpdateObjects(movies);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

and this is how I dyanmically add images to a imagelist, the Key is same as ID/Key of my object class

```
string imgloc = string.Format(@".\imgs\{0}.jpg", chunk.Id);
imageList1.Images.Add(chunk.Id, new Bitmap(imgloc));
```

Comment: What control do you want to display the images in ? This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996614/display-image-in-combobox-column-in-datagrid

Comment: This is for objectlistview

Answer (score 1):

This is unrelated to you question, but instead of

```
objectListView2.UpdateObjects(movies);
```

you probably want to use the `SetObjects` method.

Regarding using images you may find [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25501704/1790864) useful.

As a side note, while using

```
Generator.GenerateColumns(objectListView2, typeof(MovieDetails), true);
```

is easy, using the AspectGetter and AspectSetter handlers of each column gives you far more control over column contents.